# Why isn't my Flask application's global object deleted on app teardown?

Tags: unit-testing, python-3.x, flask, contextmanager, flask-testing

I am writing an application with a global object that should live as long as the application as alive. Different endpoints should mutate the global object.

Below is my server with an example mock-up object to be mutated on dummy endpoint calls.

## `server.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from flask import Flask, g, request

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = None

    def add_bar(self, bar):
        if self.bar is not None:
            raise Exception("You blew it!")
        self.bar = bar

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    return app

app = create_app()

def get_foo():
    foo = getattr(g, '_foo', None)
    if foo is None:
        print("foo is None. Creating a foo")
        foo = g._foo = Foo()
    return foo

@app.teardown_appcontext
def teardown_foo(exception):
    foo = getattr(g, '_foo', None)
    if foo is not None:
        print("Deleting foo")
        del foo

@app.route("/add_bar", methods=['POST'])
def bar():
    bar = request.form.get("bar")
    foo.add_bar(bar)
    return "Success"    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = create_app()
    app.run('localhost', port=8080)
```

Like a good software developer, I want to test this. Here's my test suite:

## `test.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from server import *
import unittest

class FlaskTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        app.config['TESTING'] = True
        print("Creating an app...")
        self.app = create_app()
        print("Created an app...")
        with self.app.app_context():
            self.foo = get_foo()

    def tearDown(self):
        del self.foo

    def test_add_bar(self):
        with self.app.test_client() as client:
            client.post("/add_bar", data={'bar': "12345"})
            assert self.foo.bar == "12345"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

When I run the test, I notice that my `foo` object is never deleted (by the prints). Here's the output when I run the test suite:

```
13:35 $ ./test.py
Creating an app...
Created an app...
foo is None. Creating a foo
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_add_bar (__main__.FlaskTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 21, in test_add_bar
    assert self.foo.bar == "12345"
AssertionError

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.009s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

I must be doing something incorrectly with my global object with respect to the application context. I've pored over the [testing documents](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/testing/), but cannot seem to find exactly what I need.

How can I ensure my `foo` object is destroyed when the application context goes out of scope (like in my tests)? Why isn't my unit test suite mutating its `foo` object that is created on `setUp`?

I thought it could be modifying the global `app` object within `server.py`, but when I printed `foo`, I found that it wasn't defined within the scope of my test suite.

Comment: `except: assert False` looks like an antipattern to me. Probably the best place to start is to remove the try/except and just let the exception bubble up. Looking at the original exception may be illuminating. (On a side note, `assert True` will always be completely useless. It seems like maybe you have some misunderstandings about how assertions should work.)

Comment: @jpmc26 I don't think I have misunderstandings about how assertions work...  I copied the test from something a bit more complicated and boiled it down. Didn't remove extraneous stuff. Will update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## This was a weird issue.

The problem was an interference between the global `app` object within the `server.py` and the app being created within the original `test.py`. Specifically, since the app was being imported, its lifetime was the life of the test suite.

I removed the global `app` object by using `flask.Blueprint`. Here's the final `server.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from flask import Flask, g, request, Blueprint

main = Blueprint('main', __name__)

def get_foo():
    foo = getattr(g, 'foo', None)
    if foo is None:
        foo = g.foo = Foo()
    return foo

@main.before_request
def before_request():
    foo = get_foo()

@main.route("/add_bar", methods=['POST'])
def bar():
    bar = request.form.get("bar")
    g.foo.add_bar(bar)
    return "Success"

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = None

    def add_bar(self, bar):
        if self.bar is not None:
            raise Exception("You blew it!")
        self.bar = bar

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.register_blueprint(main)
    @app.teardown_appcontext
    def teardown_foo(exception):
        if g.foo is not None:
            del g.foo
    return app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = create_app()
    with app.app_context():
        foo = get_foo()
        app.run('localhost', port=8080)
```

And here's the final `test.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from server import create_app, get_foo
import unittest

class FlaskTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.app = create_app()
        self.app_context = self.app.app_context()
        self.app_context.push()
        self.client = self.app.test_client()
        self.foo = get_foo()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.app_context.pop()
        del self.foo

    def test_add_bar_success(self):
        assert self.foo.bar is None
        self.client.post("/add_bar", data={'bar': "12345"})
        assert self.foo.bar == "12345"

    def test_foo_reset_on_new_test(self):
        assert self.foo.bar is None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

`test_foo_reset_on_new_test` illustrates that the `foo` object associated with the test suite is reset on each test.

All tests pass.

Answer (score 0):

Because `del foo` only unbind the variable `foo`. If you have `foo = g._foo`, then calling `del foo` would not unbind `g._foo`, but only `foo` itself.

`del` is not used to delete an object. It releases a variable name from scope.

Comment: 1. `teardown_foo` is never called. 2. `foo` and `g._foo` are the same object. 3. Unbinding a name to an object and reusing that name is the same as "deleting" an object.

Comment: @erip unbinding the name `foo` doesn't unbind the name `g._foo`. If the object is still referenced somewhere, it does not get destroyed.